# PowerShell Remove-Item using PSSession

Tags: c#, powershell, remote-access

I'm trying to create a simple file operations API for remote machine using PowerShell from C#.

I am able to `Copy-Item` to and from remote machine by first creating `New-PSSession` and executing the `Copy-Item` cmdlet with an additional parameter `-ToSession/-FromSession $s`, where `$s` is a variable generated by the `New-PSSession`.

I am looking for a way to do the same with removing, adding and moving items, but I'm already stuck with Removing part. MSDN does not specify any specific parameter in place of `-ToSession/-FromSession` - is there any other way to remove a file using PSSession? I would like to limit "ways" of connecting to remote host to a bare minimum.

Disclaimer: I am able to create a remote PowerShell client in C# and run commands remotely, but I'd rather keep the control of the process on client, not the host.

Comment: So, you do not want to run commands inside the PSSession?

Comment: I exactly want to run the Remove-Item command using PSSession, but as far as I understand I pass the session as a parameter - yet I do not know what the parameter for this command would be.

In the other way I'm using I create a runspace, add scripts and then using the remote host as the controller of the script I execute it. I would rather like to leave the control part on local client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understood, this is what you want to do:

If you want to type the path:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -Command {Remove-Item c:\windows}
```

or

Using the path as variable, you need to utilize the `$Using:` keyword. This works PoShv3 or higher.

```
$Path = 'C:\Windows'
Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -Command {Remove-Item $Using:Path}
```

or

If you need to go classic, you can pass the variables into the scriptblock by the `-argumentlist` parameter. You can pick them up inside the scriptblock by either `$args` array, or by a parameter block. Of course, the variable names inside the scriptblock can differ from the outside ones.

```
$Path = 'C:\Windows'
Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -Command {Param($Path) Remove-Item $Path} -ArgumentList $path
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you very much. Your first solution works, but I had to change `Remove-Object` to `Remove-Item`. Is this some version mismatch of Powershell maybe?

Comment: I added a bit of explanation. You might need it.

Comment: By the way `get-command -ParameterName *session` gives you a list of commands, that might be helpful (because they support the parametername *session, obviuosly)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, This makes your answer even clearer now,  I wish I could upvote twice ;)